# Java psexec interactive remote command line

Tags: java, windows, remote-access, psexec

I'm having an issue with psexec where it's not interactive. It returns as soon as it has run the command to open command prompt

Here is my Connection class:

```
package testProject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class ConTest {

    private ProcessBuilder process;
    private Process connection;
    private String main_connection;;

    public ConTest(String host, String user, String password) {
        process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
        process.redirectErrorStream(true);
        main_connection="<path to psexec>\psexec.exe \\\\" + host + 
                " -accepteula -nobanner -u " + user + " -p " + password +" cmd";
    }

    public void runCommand(String command) throws Exception{

        /* Variable Declaration */
        String          readline;
        PrintStream     output;
        BufferedReader  input;

        /* Variable Initialization */
        connection = process.start();
        output = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        /* Running the commands on the Host */

        output.println(main_connection);
        output.println(command);
        output.println("exit");
        output.close();

        /*print the output from the command*/
        while ((readline = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readline);
        }

        input.close();
        connection.waitFor();
    }
}
```

And then I'm calling it using the following

```
package testProject;

public class mainClass {

    public mainClass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConTest con = new ConTest(<IP>, <Admin>, <Password>);
        con.runCommand("ping localhost");

    }
}
```

The output shows that it connects to the host but then it just disconnects before writing the `ping localhost` command

Here is the output

```
C:><path to psexec>\psexec.exe \\<IP> -accepteula -nobanner -u <Admin> -p <Password> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]Connecting to <IP>...


Starting PSEXESVC service on <IP>...


Connecting with PsExec service on <IP>...


Starting cmd on <IP>...



cmd exited on <IP> with error code 0.

C:\>ping localhost
```

followed by the ping stats

How can I keep the command prompt the focus of the output stream so when I send more commands down the pipe they are executed on the remote machine not my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used paexec instead of psexec and it managed to give me an interactive session, hope this helps someone in the future